# Updating a dynamic form from server php javascript but needs to stay on the same page in browser

Tags: javascript, php

I have to create a form where mid way when the user is filling the input on filling one specific select input I need to send a request to the server where I tell the server which select value was selected and then the server will respond with a new page updating the form with additional input fields related to the selected option the user has chosen.

I am doing this and all is fine but when the server sends back the updated page the browser is stacking the pages. By stacking I mean that after receiving the updated form if the user presses back he will be taken to the old form that was there before the server call and the update.

I don't want this behavior I just want the browser in a way or another to have the same page but with the updated form

This is the javascript code that is triggered when a select is chosen

```
    function updateForm(value){
    let form=document.forms["form"];
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('name', "typeOfCall");
    input.setAttribute('value', 'updateForm');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    form.appendChild(input);
    form.submit();
}
```

then the server does a lot of stuff accessing the database then does the following to send back an updated page

```
    public function render_view($view,$params=[]){
    $layout = $this->get_layout();
    $view = $this->get_view($view,$params);
    return str_replace("{{content}}",$view,$layout);
}
```

The result of this function is then echoed

I am not using any framework because part of the asignment is not to use any framework

Comment: What you need here is AJAX. So JavaScript would send a HTTP AJAX request to the server, and then the server would send back a partial page from the PHP. So that way the browser stays on the same page throughout the process, but you just modify parts of it, using Javascript to update the page with the snippets of HTML that the server returns.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any external libraries you can use JavaScript Fetch API to call the server and retrieve your information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Fetch is asynchronous, so you can update your form using the response once it has been received. You can then parse and use this information to populate/edit the form.